# Multithread webservice acessing and modifying List object not threadsafe

Tags: c#, multithreading

I learnt the hard way when my multi-threaded app was modifying the same object and the List object couldn't handle the two thread adding a object to the list at the exact same time.

I did some research and found i can use a lock to avoid this from happening, after a month of the application running smoothly it happend again even with the lock object in place. I don't understand how this still cab be happening.
the error messages are the same as before:
1- Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.
2- Index was outside the bounds of the array.

in the class private members I have this member variable

```
private static readonly object _syncLock = new object();
```

in the public function

```
public Dictionary<int, QueuedLetter> GetXMLFragment(Dictionary<int, QueuedLetter> queuedLetters, GroupNode GroupNode, GroupNode ParentGroupNode, StoredProcedure storedProcedure)
```

This is where I use the _synclock object the lines of code are as followed

```
XmlFragment xf = new XmlFragment();
xf.Fragment = xe;
xf.LetterQueueOID = lq.LetterQueueOID;
xf.ParentGroupNodeName = ParentGroupNodeName;
xf.LinkingField = GroupNode.LinkingField;
xf.GroupNodeName = GroupNode.GroupNodeName;

lock (_syncLock)
{
   if (lq.Fragments == null)
      lq.Fragments = new List<XmlFragment>();
   lq.Fragments.Add(xf);
}
```

I use a thread pool to create the multi-Threading functionality in another class it calls a starting function in the same class as where the lock happens above

```
events[i] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
AttachFragments f = new AttachFragments(events[i], groupNodeOID, QueuedLetters, string.Format("Failed while fragment Data : {0}, was executing ", groupNodeName));
f.OnException += ThreadErroredOut;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(f.UpdateFragments));
```

If you can give me some advise on what I am doing wrong, that would be greatly appreciated.

I have thought about using 
the Thread-Safe Collections in .NET 4.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx
but I haven't used it and if i change it to this, this would cause big changes in the code which would require a more in depth testing by are Q.A. team.

The stack traces of the two exceptions:
1- Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.:
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item)     at JE.ThunderHead.Business.AttachFragments.GetXMLFragment(Dictionary`2 queuedLetters, GroupNode GroupNode, GroupNode ParentGroupNode, StoredProcedure storedProcedure) in C:\TFS\LMS\Release\LM_05\LM_05.01\Solutions\ThunderHead\JE.Thunderhead.Business\AttachFragments.cs:line 135     at JE.ThunderHead.Business.AttachFragments.UpdateFragments(Object stateinfo) in C:\TFS\LMS\Release\LM_05\LM_05.01\Solutions\ThunderHead\JE.Thunderhead.Business\AttachFragments.cs:line 99

2- Index was outside the bounds of the array:
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)     at JE.ThunderHead.Business.AttachFragments.GetXMLFragment(Dictionary`2 queuedLetters, GroupNode GroupNode, GroupNode ParentGroupNode, StoredProcedure storedProcedure) in C:\TFS\LMS\Release\LM_05\LM_05.01\Solutions\ThunderHead\JE.Thunderhead.Business\AttachFragments.cs:line 231

Comment: Do you have a stack trace confirming what part of the code it's coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the stack trace you posted, it looks like there's an `Insert` on that list that you're not showing here. If that's the case, you'll need to lock around that `Insert` as well using the same lock object.

Comment: I think you are right I was looking at this section before you posted it. I will let you know if this solved the problem and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: it's been almost two months and it hasn't happened again Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

I can say with certainty that the code snippet you show will not be updating `lq` concurrently.

I can't however tell you much more without more of your code. It might be better to subclass whatever class `lq` is and put the locking in that implementation. After that I could tell you for sure `lq` was thread safe.

I think you should consider refactoring to use [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) as you suggested. Despite the cost for the Q.A. cycle you would get an assurance of quality and the potential performance improvement of interlocked operations and thread spinning.